# Is Quality of Service my ISP's responsibility?

Tags: networking, qos, bottleneck

One person on my network does a massive download, not caring too much about how long it takes. Someone else on my network doesn't want his incessant video streaming interrupted. My understanding is that this is solved using QoS, to prioritize streaming packets over update downloads, or packets from one source over another source.

However, I think the link that gets congested here is the one between me and my ISP. I am guessing that if QoS was configured on my end, packets would still be sent indiscriminately to my router, they would still de-bottleneck even though my router is prioritizing them, and there would be no difference in performance. (I attempted to include a diagram to explain this but apparently I don't have enough reputation.)

If I wanted the streamer's stuff to be prioritized, would that  have to be set up on the ISP's end or is there anything I can do on my own network?

I apologize for my noobishness.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because everything about it is a dumpster fire.

Comment: Your ISP will not honor your QoS policies or markings, and neither will any other ISPs through which your traffic passes through the Internet, in either direction (that would be illegal in, at least, the U.S. due to network neutrality). There really isn't anything you can do about incoming traffic since the bandwidth is already used by the time you see the traffic. You _can_ drop it in your network, but the incoming bandwidth has been used.

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to solve the problem you describe. QoS is largely about controlling packets going out of your network not so much coming in.

Most ISPs won't do a thing about QoS either because the Internet is more about general availability then reliability (think: "can I access a website" instead of "is the connection reliable").

The only possible solution would be some sort of network inspection device ("next gen firewall" or IDS) where you could create rules to selectively drop traffic matching a pattern ("person X is consuming much bandwidth") but those are expensive, complicated, and not neccicary effective.

Comment: The bandwidth is already used by the time you see the incoming traffic.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that QoS is a LAN thing, and the ISP will likely just be sending packets where they are needed. You can implement QoS on your network for LAN usage but it wont affect your ISPs link to you.

QoS will prioritize which packets will be processed first.